# Alpha Testing of App on iOS and Android

Tags: ios, android-testing, ad-hoc-distribution, beta-testing

We developed an app for our client. We're ready to alpha/beta test the app already using Apple's Ad Hoc Distribution and Google's Beta Testing and Stage Roll-Outs feature. Should we use our own developer's account on Apple and Google to publish the app or should we use our client's developer's account? Is there any conflict if we use our account during the development and beta testing and use our client's account for the final distribution for app store/Google Play?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

**Android App Distribution**

Android Stage roll out feature provides you to upload apps for just to alpha/beta testing, so it wont be visible to users other than registered alpha users(which are generally members of a specific google group chosen by you). Later you can promote that alpha app to beta or production. 
Answer to your question: You can use seperate accounts provided you maintain different identifiers (for example com.MyCompanyName.appName ) for both apps. But that just defeats the staged rollout feature of Play Store Distribution features. I would suggest you to use client's account because anyway you app has limited visibility during alpha/beta testing phases.

**iPhone App Distribution**

iPhone App distribution is a bit different. You can create multiple distribution profiles. So say you create adhoc distribution profile to test your app using your developer account but for app store distribution you create profile using client's developer account. But again why would you switch accounts(for testing/producation) when app distribution handles it for you.